# how to set range without max values in vue-slider

Tags: vue.js, slider, vue-slider-component

I am using [vueSlider](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component).

Looking at the example below link, I think that only the integers in min and max can be set.

```
<vue-slider
ref="slider"
v-model="value"
min="0"
max="100"
```

> 

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/NightCatSama/2xy72dod/10547/)

But I would like to set a range that is not an integer.
For example, I want to set the value from 30 seconds to 1:30 minutes in the range.

Is there a way to implement something like the above example in vue-slider?

If it could not, please let me know if you have any alternatives.

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formatter if you want show vue-slider value in second:

```
  <vue-slider
    ref="slider"
    v-model="value"
    v-bind="options"
    :min="15"
    :max="360"
    :interval= "1"
    :tooltip="'always'"
    :tooltip-formatter="Tformatter"
  >
  </vue-slider>
```

```
new Vue( {
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      value: 15,
      Tformatter: val => {
        let min = Math.floor(val/60);
        let sec = val%60 > 9 ? val%60 : "0"+val%60;
        return min+':'+sec;
      }
    }
  },
```

Here is updated your example : https://jsfiddle.net/d1qwx3gv/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it

remove min and max you won't need them

what you need to use is the :data property which can take an array of values
(numbers or strings e.t.c)

a small implementation would be like this

e.x.

```
<div id="app">
   <vue-slider :data="datas" v-model="vvalue"  :marks="true"></vue-slider>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    message:'hi there',
    vvalue:'30',
    datas:['30','45','1:00','1:30']
  },
  components: {
    VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
  }
})
```

you can check a working example here also
https://jsfiddle.net/9ejrwz2t/1/